# Laravel Auth user id in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the Laravel boilerplate. I'm trying to get the `user_id` of the signed in user. I am getting the following error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth' not found

Here is the call

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Then I try to get the id using:

```
$user->id
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use the Auth facade in the controller;

add this line just before class definition.

```
use Auth;
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this,

```
auth()->user()->id;
```

When you try to get the user by using `$user = Auth::user();` Laravel tries to load Auth class from the current location. In your case, it is

> 'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend'

So Laravel is looking for Auth class inside the Frontend directory, which is not in. That's why you got that error message saying not found as below,

> 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth' not found'

If you use `use Auth;` method, you have to type `use Auth;` in each and every controller that you are going to use the Auth controller.

Instead of typing `use Auth;` in each and every controller you can simply use the Laravel helper function as `auth()->user()`.

from that you can get any value from the db like:

```
auth()->user()->id

auth()->user()->f_name
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

Add the following line before the Class definition

```
use Auth;
```

Get your current user id using the following code:

```
$currentuserid = Auth::user()->id;
```

Comment: Incredible answer! Thanks!